# Git bash pull/push checker for repo to batch equivalent

Tags: git, batch-file, cmd

I have been struggling to build a batch equivalent code for git repo to check if the repo requires a pull or push? I have the git-bash version of the code which is working perfectly but I need the BAT version to have it connected with other codes.

```
cd $GITDIR ;
git fetch ;

UPSTREAM=${1:-'@{u}'} ;
LOCAL=$(git rev-parse @) ;
REMOTE=$(git rev-parse "$UPSTREAM") ;
BASE=$(git merge-base @ "$UPSTREAM") ;

#echo $UPSTREAM
#echo $ROMOTE
#echo $LOCAL

if [ $LOCAL = $REMOTE ]; then
    echo "Up-to-date" ;
elif [ $LOCAL = $BASE ]; then
    echo "Need to pull" ;
elif [ $REMOTE = $BASE ]; then
    echo "Need to push" ;
else
    echo "Diverged" ;
fi
```

I narrowed down the issue and I think it has something to do in the following lines where it gets the remote commit id, base commit if, and the local commit id which is further used to compare and decide if PULL/PUSH are required.

```
UPSTREAM=${1:-'@{u}'} ;
LOCAL=$(git rev-parse @) ;
REMOTE=$(git rev-parse "$UPSTREAM") ;
BASE=$(git merge-base @ "$UPSTREAM") ;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This question seems to be "what are the CMD.EXE equivalents of these sh/bash constructs". I replaced one tag with [tag:cmd], but if I'm right, probably that should be the only tag.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend keeping the bash version, considering it would work on Windows as well

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" -h always /bin/bash -l -e 'C:\path\to\script.sh'
```

That way, no need to translate those shell string manipulations into BAT equivalent.